# How do I access a typedef struct pointer to an internal object with ctypes?

Tags: python, c, shared-libraries, ctypes

I'm using ctypes in Python 3.6 to interface with a C library. One of the functions enables the library and returns a type definition to an internal object which needs to be passed to subsequent function calls. Here's an example:

```
// Type definition of the internal object.
typedef struct lib_internal_obj * lib_internal_obj_t;

/**
 * Struct containing the available options for the library
 */
struct lib_options {
        char ip[255];         
        int bufsize_MB;    
};

/** Constructor of a lib object.
 * \return A newly created lib object or NULL if construction failed
 */
extern lib_internal_obj_t    lib_internal_obj_new(struct lib_options * options); 


/**
 * Example of how the internal object is used. 
 *
 */
extern int     lib_get_options(lib_internal_obj_t obj, struct lib_options *options);

/**
 * Destructor of the lib object.
 */
extern void    lib_del(lib_internal_obj_t *obj);
```

I'm lost on how this object gets returned and stored with ctypes in Python. I assumed it works like normal function calls in Python. Here is what I tried:

```
import ctypes as c

class LIB_OPTIONS(c.Structure):
    """Struct containing the available options for the library"""
    _fields_ = [
        ('ip', c.c_char * 255),
        ('bufsize_MB', c.c_int)
    ]

# Open C lib
c_lib = c.CDLL('./path/to/lib/lib.so', mode=1)

# Set options
lib_opts = LIB_OPTIONS()
lib_opts.ip = "192.168.1.1".encode('utf-8')
lib_opts.bufsize_MB = 2

# Not sure how to handle this
lib_object = c_lib.lib_internal_obj_new(c.byref(lib_opts))
```

When I run this I get the following error:

```
Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

I'm pretty sure this has something to do with the `clib.lib_internal_obj_new` call. Is there a way to return a typedef struct and store it properly from ctypes. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual reason for problems with `ctypes` is not defining `.argtypes` and `.restype` for the functions being called.  In particular, the return type defaults to an `c_int` (typically 32-bit) and on a 64-bit system your function would return a 64-bit pointer.

```
import ctypes as c

class LIB_OPTIONS(c.Structure):
    """Struct containing the available options for the library"""
    _fields_ = [('ip', c.c_char * 255),
                ('bufsize_MB', c.c_int)]

c_lib = c.CDLL('./test')
c_lib.lib_internal_obj_new.argtypes = c.POINTER(LIB_OPTIONS), # 1-tuple declaring input parameter
c_lib.lib_internal_obj_new.restype = c.c_void_p # generic pointer

lib_opts = LIB_OPTIONS(b'192.168.1.1',2)
lib_object = c_lib.lib_internal_obj_new(c.byref(lib_opts))
```

Comment: Thank you. So this may constitute another question, but how would you pass the lib_object to "c_lib.lib_del"? I tried passing it as a c_void_p, but I'm getting a segmentation fault.

Comment: @jms Set `c_lib.lib_del.argtypes = c_void_p,` and call `c_lib.lib_del(lib_object)`.  If you still have problems, post some minimal implementation of the C functions.